Crystal material,blender export glb file texture loss, texture baking effect is very bad, is there any way to fix
maybe it is caused by glass bsdf, makes the export not correct

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

First of all, just as linked by @DuarteFarrajotaRamos it simply is often not possible to recreate Blender-specific materials in other file formats / software. You are right, the Glass BSDF for example is not supported in glTF. Read more about it here: Blender Manual: glTF import-export

Also you can't expect to bake the dynamic aspect of a shader into an image, which is by essence static. Reflections, refractions and diffractions are not bakable. This shader would need to be constructed in your target rendering software.
